Notepad++ find and replace string
I've been trying to do this for a while now. It's 900+ of line.
I want to replace the password and the name to be the same.
Example:
add name="QHGG4U8M" password="" profile="2h" comment="vc-422-01.02.24-2h-Q-" limit-uptime="2h"
add name="UKBSYR8K" password="" profile="6h" comment="vc-195-01.09.24-6h-U-" limit-uptime="6h"

Desired result:
add name="QHGG4U8M" password="QHGG4U8M" profile="2h" comment="vc-422-01.02.24-2h-Q-" limit-uptime="2h"
add name="UKBSYR8K" password="UKBSYR8K" profile="6h" comment="vc-195-01.09.24-6h-U-" limit-uptime="6h"



Ctrl+H
Find what: add name="(.+?)" password="\K
Replace with: $1
TICK Wrap around
Search Mode Regular expression
Replace all

Explanation:
add name="          # literally
(.+?)               # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
" password="        # literally
\K                  # match reset operator, forget all we have seen until this position

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):


huh, neat trick! the \K says "forget all we saw so far", and since we did get a match everything we saw (nothing) gets replaced with the group from the match. I would've done it the "replace text1 (group1) text2 bla" with "text1 (group1) text2 (group1)" way which is easier to understand, but I like this little trick!

@Syndic: It acts like a variable length lookbehind that is not supported in all regex flavour.
